# Integrating Factor - Exact Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"Find the solution of the DE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x-e^y}, \qquad  y(1) = 0, \qquad dx - (x-e^y)\,dy = 0$$

This isn't in the form of an exact equation right? I was going to try and find an itnegrating factor, but doesn't $M$ and $N$ have to be fucntions of $x$ and/or $y$ first?

Comment: Yes. Are not $M=1$ and $N=e^y-x$ functions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I...I thought since $M$ is equal to a constant it wasn't a function of $x$ and $y$. Is it a function of those two variables since $x$ and $y$ are basically... zero?

Comment: No, we don't say $x$ and $y$ are zero. Constant functions are functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $M = 1$ and $N = e^y - x$.  Then, $M_y = 0$ whereas $N_x = -1$, which implies ODE is not exact.  However, if there exists an integrating factor, we guarantee the new ODE is exact.  Since the partial derivatives of $M$ and $N$ are constant functions, there exists an integrating factor that works for ODE.

$$\begin{aligned}
f(y) &= \dfrac{N_x - M_y}{M} = -1\\
\mu(y) &= e^{\int f(y)\,dy} = e^{-y}
\end{aligned}$$

So the new $M$ and $N$ are $M' = e^{-y}$ and $N' = 1 - xe^{-y}$.  Then, $M_y' = -e^{-y}$ and $N_x' = -e^{-y}$, which shows the new ODE is exact.  Therefore,

$$\begin{aligned}
\int e^{-y}\,dx &= \int (1 - xe^{-y})\,dy\\
xe^{-y} + \varphi(y) &= y + xe^{-y} + \gamma(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Since $\varphi(y) = y$ and $\gamma(x) = 0$, the general solution is
$$xe^{-y} + y = \mbox{C}$$

Comment: Done.  Misread your comments, but thanks!

Comment: Why do you say an integrating factor exists because $M_y$ and $N_x$ are constant functions? Is that a condition for an integrating factor of an exact equation?

Comment: Look at $M = 1$, $N = e^y - x$, $M_y = 0$ and $N_x = -1$.  Since $M$, $M_y$ and $N_x$ are constants, we find that $f(y) = -1$ as already mentioned in my answer.  This is the condition that an integrating factor exists.  We can't construct $g(x)$ from $M_y$, $N_x$ and $N$ since $M_y$ and $N_x$ are constants, and $N$ has two variables.  I hope this logic works. ;)